# Symfony2/Doctrine2 : I would like to get the data from user information

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

```
My\SampleBundle\Entity\Subject:

    // ...

    manyToOne:
        author:
            targetEntity: My\UserBundle\Entity\User
            joinColumn:
                name: owner
                referencedColumnName: id
```

The user relevant to a subject can acquire.

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
              ->createQuery('
                  SELECT s, a
                  FROM MySampleBundle:Subject s
                  LEFT JOIN s.author a
                  WHERE s.author = :author
                  GROUP BY s.title'
              )
              ->setParameter("author", $author);
```

On the contrary, how should I get a subject from user information?

For example, the query in a user list page.

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
              ->createQuery('
                  SELECT u
                  FROM MyUserBundle:User u
                  GROUP BY u.username'
              );
```

At this time, I would like to also get the data of a related subjects.

I use FOSUserBundle.
Is it a problem which should just correct an My\UserBundle\Entity?
Or is it wrong from the stage of a orm setting?

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer below. Explain shortly what you changed and how that solved it. This will make it a perfect Q&A entry then. Let me know if you run into any problems. And yes, it's okay to answer your own questions (and accept the answer then).

Comment: OK, it adds to the text.  But it was not perfect solution. Easy data has been acquired. However, it stops answering, when join table increases, and it will be in the state of loading all the time. I think that data is not necessarily too heavy. The problem is not understood yet.

Comment: Even if you're not 100% satisfied with the answer, please not just edit your question but add it as an answer *below* (new empty box). After you have answered your question and some little time has passed, you can accept it as the answer which will mark your question as "solved". At least for other users it's more clear what the question and what the answer is. This might even attract others that might leave another answer, too.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure which I modified.

STEP:1 add to My\UserBundle\Entity\User

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="My\SampleBundle\Entity\Subject", mappedBy="author")
 */
private $subjects;

/**
 * Get subjects
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getSubjects()
{
    return $this->subjects;
}
```

STEP:2 add 'inversedBy'

```
My\SampleBundle\Entity\Subject:
    type: entity

    // ...

    manyToOne:
        author:
            targetEntity: My\UserBundle\Entity\User
            inversedBy: subjects
            joinColumn:
                name: owner
                referencedColumnName: id
```

STEP:3 query

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
              ->createQuery('
                  SELECT u, s
                  FROM MyUserBundle:User u
                  LEFT JOIN u.subjects s
                  ORDER BY u.username'
              );
```

Easy data has been acquired. 
But it was not perfect solution.

It stops answering, when join table increases, and it will be in the state of loading all the time.
I think that data is not necessarily too heavy.
The problem is not understood yet.

The example of another issue

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
              ->createQuery('
                  SELECT u, s, a, c, i
                  FROM MyUserBundle:User u
                  LEFT JOIN u.subjects s
                  LEFT JOIN u.articles a
                  LEFT JOIN u.comments c
                  LEFT JOIN u.images i
                  // etc...
                  // It will be in the state of loading all the time
                  // when join table increases.
                  ORDER BY u.username'
              );
```

Comment: They were my imagination. 
A page function is also involved and I think that it is because there was too much data. 
I think that fundamental data acquisition is OK now.